# How to fix the IE8 favorites menu (little box icon)?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, bookmarks, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I'm using Windows XP and Internet Explorer 8, and occasionally one off my favorites (Link) folders will get a very small box in the upper right corner (on the favorites menu drop down itself) and not open at all.  I can't figure out how it got there or how to disable it, and I have to completely shut IE down and restart it to get rid of it.

Any clues on what's going on?

In Windows 7 the box is really small, but it's still there, and the same behavior:

[image: Little Box Favorites Menu]

Comment: To clarify: you're talking about Favorites on the main IE8 menu, between View and Tools, and when you drop down the list of Favorites from there, sometimes one of the Favorites - a folder (not a shortcut) - has a small box in the top left corner of the folder icon?  Does the icon itself disappear?  What about the folder name?

Comment: Actually, top right corner of the folder icon.  Nothing disappears, it just won't open.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to your question?

Comment: @CarlF, I'll do that the next time it comes up, it's pretty arbitrary.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of this ?

Comment: @harrymc, I still don't have one, never have remembered to take one when it happens.

Comment: If this happens in IE 9 now, is it not safe to assume that you are not using XP? Should this be re-tagged or the question updated?

Comment: @RedriderX, yes, good point, I'm now using Windows 7 mostly.  I've edited the tags.

Comment: Do you have antivirus programs running and if so, which? And was it the same brand on both Xp and W7?

Comment: @Manwe, Yes, on the AV, but no, they were different programs.

Comment: Do you use any extra plugins or do you have some kind of link checker (could be AV) that tests are you favourites valid. This could lock/screw-up "cached" favourites for ie. This is just a wild guess not based on any experience.

Comment: @Manwe, no, not really, and I've seen this on quite a few different computers.

Comment: That 'little box icon' is actually the Windows that supposed to auto expand on hover, it failing to expand so you only see a 1 or 2px square which are the borders for the window; but it has no height or width for some reason.  I can think of a few.

You updated to say it still exists in Windows 7.  Is this the same hardware as when you witnessed it in XP?  Did you upgrade from XP to 7, or do a clean install on a formatted disk?

Comment: @techie007, on Windows 7 I've seen it on clean install machines.

Answer (score 1):

Can't hurt to check out "Fix IE Utility"

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/repair-internet-explorer-with-fix-ie-utility

Answer (score 1):

Favorites are normally stored in C:\Documents and Settings\\Favorites.  Take a look at the folder in Windows Explorer - check for weird files and delete anything that isn't a folder or a shortcut.

Comment: It's not a behavior that sticks around.  If you open a different window with IE in it, it doesn't have it.  Or you can just open and close the current window, and it goes away.